# Is there a DSA technique for transform feedback?

Tags: opengl, transform-feedback

The typical way I see transform feedback being used is:

```
    glGenBuffers(1, &tbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, tbo);
    glBufferData(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, sizeof(data), nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
```

However, new, DSA OpenGL eschews the binding points.  Is there a DSA way to bind a buffer to the transform feedback binding point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding points (and other state) are still important when doing actual draw calls (stuff like VAOs, UBOs, SSBOs and programs are still bound). It's only bind-to-edit that was eschewed.

In your case the most DSA way to do that would be:

```
glCreateBuffers(1, &tbo);
glNamedBufferData(tbo,sizeof(data), nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);

glBindBuffer(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, tbo);
```

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a DSA way to bind buffers to the feedback buffer bindings. But that's because [transform feedbacks are *objects*](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transform_Feedback#Feedback_objects), and there *is* a DSA way to attach buffers to transform feedback objects:

```
GLuint buffer;
glCreateBuffers(1, &buffer);
//Fill in buffer's data.

GLuint feedback;
glCreateTransformFeedbacks(1, &feedback);
glTransformFeedbackBufferRange(feedback, 0, buffer, offset, size);
```

You can then bind `feedback` when you're ready to actually do your feedback operations into those buffers.